# Can we insert in one table and trigger to update the inserted row's one column by looking at other table's value for the id being inserted?

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, triggers

How to write a trigger which upon `insert` in `table3` looks at `table1` if the `code` and `id` has a `price` there first and updates the `price` of `table3` accordingly. But if the `id`+`code` cannot be found then it looks in `table2` for the `id` and uses that price to calculate the total `price` and updates the `price` in `table3` for that insert.

table1

```
| id | code | price |
|----|------|-------|
| 1  | fire | 3     |
| 2  | ice  | 4     |
| 3  | air  | 5     |
```

table2

```
| id | price |
|----|-------|
| 1  | 8     |
| 2  | 9     |
```

table3

```
| id | code | qty | price |
|----|------|-----|-------|
| 1  | fire | 2   |       | -- price = 2 * 3 = 6
| 2  | none | 3   |       | -- price = 3 * 9 = 27
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your trigger function you should use `if exists` to check it.
You can write your trigger function like below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION update_price()
RETURNS trigger AS $$
  BEGIN

if exists (select price from table1 where code=new.code and id=new.id) then
new.price= new.qty * (select price from table1 where code=new.code and id=new.id);
else
new.price= new.qty * (select price from table2 where id=new.id);
end if;
  
    return new;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then you can write your trigger on `table3` as below:

```
create trigger update_price 
before insert
on table3
for each row 
execute procedure update_price();
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=4c3884ed53d8e0cd6a97572e04213b68)

Comment: thanks, akhilesh.  it worked like a charm. the declare final_price int; can be removed as it is unused.

Comment: Yes it is not required. While writing i thought with a variable but then not used it.  Updated the answer